# How to loop through a text file with mac automator commands using bash?

Tags: bash, git-bash, automator

I have a text file named `jwglist_safari_temp.txt` with the below contents:

```
U:/ryerrams_DevOct10/faat/fusionapps/crm/oats/src/cdrm/bat/WorkManagement/390_050_010 Validation of assess opportunity functionality/390_050_010 Validation of assess opportunity functionality.jwg
U:/ryerrams_DevOct10/faat/fusionapps/crm/oats/src/cdrm/bat/WorkManagement/014_020_020_1190 RBA API - Verify Get Score API with does not equal operator on Attr/014_020_020_1190 RBA API - Verify Get Score API with does not equal operator on Attr.jwg
U:/ryerrams_DevOct10/faat/fusionapps/crm/oats/src/cdrm/bat/WorkManagement/014_0140_020_010 Verify that the correct Territories get returned for a sales Account/014_0140_020_010 Verify that the correct Territories get returned for a sales Account.jwg
U:/ryerrams_DevOct10/faat/fusionapps/crm/oats/src/cdrm/bat/WorkManagement/014_040_010_1400 Invoke Batch Assignment using View Criteria Name for TBA/014_040_010_1400 Invoke Batch Assignment using View Criteria Name for TBA.jwg
```

I am using Git-Bash to execute the below command:

```
while read p; do
echo $p
done <F:/CRM/Research/ryerrams/jwglist_safari_temp.txt
```

It works and the below output is shown:

```
U:/ryerrams_DevOct10/faat/fusionapps/crm/oats/src/cdrm/bat/WorkManagement/390_050_010 Validation of assess opportunity functionality/390_050_010 Validation of assess opportunity functionality.jwg
U:/ryerrams_DevOct10/faat/fusionapps/crm/oats/src/cdrm/bat/WorkManagement/014_020_020_1190 RBA API - Verify Get Score API with does not equal operator on Attr/014_020_020_1190 RBA API - Verify Get Score API with does not equal operator on Attr.jwg
U:/ryerrams_DevOct10/faat/fusionapps/crm/oats/src/cdrm/bat/WorkManagement/014_0140_020_010 Verify that the correct Territories get returned for a sales Account/014_0140_020_010 Verify that the correct Territories get returned for a sales Account.jwg
U:/ryerrams_DevOct10/faat/fusionapps/crm/oats/src/cdrm/bat/WorkManagement/014_040_010_1400 Invoke Batch Assignment using View Criteria Name for TBA/014_040_010_1400 Invoke Batch Assignment using View Criteria Name for TBA.jwg
```

Now I am connecting to a Mac VirtualBox VM and running 2 automator workflows before and after the echo. Using the below commands:

```
while read p; do
  ssh ryerrams@10.209.163.169 "/usr/bin/automator ~/Documents/Launch_Agent.workflow"
  echo $p
  ssh ryerrams@10.209.163.169 "/usr/bin/automator ~/Documents/Stop_Agent.workflow"
done <F:/CRM/Research/ryerrams/jwglist_safari_temp.txt
```

This executes the loop only once and stops with the below output:

```
(
)
U:/ryerrams_DevOct10/faat/fusionapps/crm/oats/src/cdrm/bat/WorkManagement/390_050_010 Validation of assess opportunity functionality/390_050_010 Validation of assess opportunity functionality.jwg
(
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @Cyrus Fixed it